What is the interpretation of $R $-points on $ \mathbb{P}^n $ and $\mathbb{P}(H^0(\mathbb{P}^n_k, \mathcal{O}(d))) $?
I’m trying to understand how $ R $-points on certain parameter spaces are described and interpreted. Specifically, consider the following spaces:

$ \mathbb{P}^n_k $, the projective space over ( k ), and
$ \mathbb{P}(H^0(\mathbb{P}^n_k, \mathcal{O}(d))) $, the projective space of global sections of $ \mathcal{O}(d) $ on $ \mathbb{P}^n_k $, which parameterizes degree $ d $ hypersurfaces in $ \mathbb{P}^n_k $.

Given a morphism $ f: \operatorname{Spec}(R) \to M $, where $ M $ is one of the above spaces and ( R ) is a commutative ring, my understanding is as follows:

For $M = \mathbb{P}^n_k $:
An ( R )-point is given by a tuple of homogeneous coordinates $ [x_0 : x_1 : \cdots : x_n] $, where $ x_i \in R $, not all zero, defined up to scaling. This represents a single point in $ \mathbb{P}^n_k $ over $ R $.

For $ M = \mathbb{P}(H^0(\mathbb{P}^n_k, \mathcal{O}(d))) $:
An $ R $-point is given by a degree $ d $ homogeneous polynomial $ F \in R[x_0, \ldots, x_n] $, also defined up to scaling. This corresponds to a degree $ d $ hypersurface in $ \mathbb{P}^n_k $ over $ R $.


My question is:

Is this interpretation correct?
If so, how does this perspective help understand families of hypersurfaces or points in projective space when $ R $ is not a field (e.g., $ R = k[t] $ or a DVR)?

If there are any mistakes in the phrasing or if I’ve misunderstood the analogy, please let me know!

It’s not correct unless the only line bundle on spec R is the trivial one. Look up what the functor of points of projective space is.

It isn't correct in general. For example, for a field extension $K/k$, suppose $\pi_{a}$ denotes the ring homomorphism
$$k[T_{1},\ldots,T_{n}]\rightarrow K\enspace \, (T_{i}\mapsto a_{i})_{I}.$$
You can construct $n$ corresponding morphisms $\operatorname{Spec}K\rightarrow \textbf{P}_{k}^{n}$ since for all $i$, $T_{0}/T_{i},\ldots,T_{n}/T_{i}\backslash 1$ is an algebraically independent set, and so $\textbf{P}^{n}_{k}$ contains $n$ copies of $\textbf{A}^{n}_{k}$.
What you might be thinking about are the set of rational points of the canonical structural morphism $\textbf{P}^{n}_{k}\rightarrow k$, which is indeed in bijective correspondence with the elements of $\textbf{P}(k^{n+1})$. This result can be found in Qing Liu's book 'Algebraic Geometry and Arithmetic Curves', on pages 53-54.

Thanks for the response, actually in the case of R is discrete valuation this this equivalence appears to hold for hypersurfaces. Please see, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1912.08779 (3.2.2), however I wanted more general ideal of this. However, thank you for providing a counter example.

Furthermore, this actually what I am stating, you have just used a particular case $R=K$, I am asking of the correspondence, with $\mathbb{P}^n_K$
